# 500 Internal Server Error / Контактная форма / Проблема с переводом

Tags: laravel, vue.js, сервер, google-translate

Я пытаюсь выслать сообщение в моей контакт форме с веб-сайта на локальном сервере и производственном сервере. В локальном это работает, но не на производственном сервере. После ввода необходимых данных в контактную форму и нажатия кнопки Отправить я получаю сообщение "500 Internal Server Error". Проблема заключается в контроллере в переводе моего сообщения.Это не относится к конфигурации PHP mail для локальных серверов или почты, потому что без перевода она работает. - Что случилось? В чем может быть причина, спасибо

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'message' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required'
]);
$Translate = New Translate();
$message = $Translate->translate_via_api_key('', 'ru', $request->message);

$request->request->set('message', $message .  $request->message);


try{
    Mail::to(\setting('site.contact_email'))->send(new ContactMail($request->all()));
}catch(\Exception $e){
    return response()->json(['errors' => ['Error try again']], 200);
}

return response()->json(true);
```

}

Comment: Мало информации
Попробуйте внести весь код под ```try{}```, а потом в блоке ```catch``` верните само исключение: ```return response()->json(['errors' => $e], 422);```

Comment: спасибо, уже разобралась, проблема была в composer.json